# Finite mass excitations of $AdS_{3}$

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, asymptotics

Consider the following extract from page 2 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9712251.pdf).

> AdS3 is the $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ group manifold and accordingly has an
>   $SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{L} \otimes SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{R}$ isometry group. In order to define the quantum theory on $AdS_3$, we must specify boundary conditions at infinity. These should be relaxed enough to allow finite mass excitations and the action of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{L} \otimes SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{R}$, but tight enough to allow a well-defined action of the diffeomorphism group.

What do finite mass excitations of $AdS_{3}$ mean?

**Edit:**

When the excerpt says

*In order to define the quantum theory on $AdS_{3}$, we must specify boundary conditions at infinity.*

I think that it means

*in order to define a quantum theory of gravity on an asymptotically $AdS_{3}$ spacetime, we must specify the asymptotic behaviour of the metric components towards infinity.*

For some reason, people have been trying to formulate quantum theories of gravity on asymptotically $(A)dS_{D}$ spacetime. Furthermore, an asymptotically $AdS_{3}$ spacetime is defined *not* by boundary conditions on the metric components *at* infinity, but by the *asymptotic* behaviour of the metric components *towards* infinity.

So, really, there is a whole bunch of asymptotically $AdS_{3}$ spacetimes, each with different masses. The global $AdS_{3}$ spacetime is the asymptotically $AdS_{3}$ spacetime of lowest mass. Asymptotically $AdS_{3}$ spacetimes with larger masses *are said to have* finite mass excitations.

So, let's come to the question *not* of mass excitations of $AdS_{3}$ spacetime ($AdS_{3}$ spacetime has a definite value of mass, so the question of mass excitations is moot), but of mass excitations of asymptotically $AdS_{3}$ spacetime.

The global $AdS_{3}$ spacetime is a vacuum solution of Einstein's equation. Furthermore, one could think of the vacuum as the space with the maximal amount of symmetry. Seen in this light, one could generate mass excitations of asymptotically $AdS_{3}$ spacetimes by reducing the amount of symmetry.

Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: I'm guessing perturbative excitations. I.e. non-solitonic

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Can you be more precise?

Comment: Precise about non-solitonic objects? Those would be fundamental strings (in string picture). Or more generally, modes whose mass doesn't go to infinity as corresponding coupling goes to zero.

Comment: There is no string theory in the extract I copied.

Comment: Then what are the dynamical objects? The latter still apply.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339915/2451