# Boundary conditions due to local and global diffeomorphisms

Tags: general-relativity, boundary-conditions, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, diffeomorphism-invariance

Consider the following extract from page 2 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712251).

> $AdS_3$ is the $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ group manifold and accordingly has an
>   $SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{L} \times SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{R}$ isometry group. In order to define the quantum theory on $AdS_3$, we must specify boundary conditions at infinity. These should be relaxed enough to allow finite mass excitations and the action of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{L} \times SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{R}$, but tight enough to allow a well-defined action of the diffeomorphism group.

---

$SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{L} \times SL(2, \mathbb{R})_{R}$ encodes global transformations of $AdS_{3}$:

1. These transformations transform a physical state into a different physical state.
2. These transformations reach infinity.

Local spacetime diffeomorphisms of $AdS_{3}$ encode gauge transformations of $AdS_{3}$:

1. These transformations transform a physical state into itself.
2. These transformations do not reach infinity.

---

Why must boundary conditions on a spacetime be *relaxed enough* to allow the action of global transformations, but *tight enough* to allow a *well-defined* action of the local diffeomorphism group.

I know that global transformations and the diffeomorphism group are definitely in tension, but I do not understand what the words *relaxed enough*, *tight enough* and *well-defined* mean.

Comment: There are several things wrong/unclear with the excerpt: While both $\mathrm{AdS}_3$ and $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1$, the natural group structure on the latter (addition in the first two coordinates, multiplication on the circle) is *not* the group structure of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and AdS doesn't carry a group structure, so it's unclear how the former is supposed to be the "group manifold" of the latter. Why would that lead to the "isometry group" being two copies of $\mathrm{SL}(2)$? $\mathrm{SL}(2)$ doesn't even carry a metric a priori!

Comment: The paper is probably unclear (it can't be wrong - this excerpt is taken from a section of the paper which reviews Brown-Henneaux central charge - this is a seminal discovery and was important to the discovery of AdS/CFT). This paper by Strominger is itself a ground-breaking paper in black hole entropy as well as its microstates and relates Cardy's asymptotic growth of states with the BTZ entropy). Chapter 1 of this thesis-
 https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.deboer/education/projects/projects/holsheimer.pdf - reviews relevant topics.

Comment: @nightmarish And that'd be... a proof by authority? ;-)  More seriously, it is definitely true that this excerpt of the paper is incredibly imprecise and unclear at best, from a mathematical standpoint. That doesn't necessarily invalidate the physical analysis in the rest of the paper, nor does it really mean the author doesn't know what he's talking about. It probably just means he doesn't care about being mathematically precise (and that's OK! Though I don't like it).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Just brainstorming: I think that physicists like to implicitly put bi-invariant metrics on their Lie groups, and then you get an isometry (sub)group $G_L\times G_R$, with the labels indicating from which side you're supposed to act. So in that sense at least $SL(2,\Bbb R)$ has these isometries and then one may declare the homeomorphism to $AdS_3$ to be an isometric diffeomorphism, I guess...

Comment: @CuriousMind Now that I think about it, I find that the review of Brown-Henneaux central charge is poorly written. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "boundary conditions" (BCs) in the [AdS/CFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/CFT_correspondence) (or equivalently in the [Graham-Fefferman](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Fefferman-Graham+ambient+construction)) settings, we don't mean boundary conditions ON the boundary $r=\infty$, but rather fall-off conditions NEAR the boundary $r\to\infty$. One the  [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) side, one should specify fall-off conditions on the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. The actual BCs are usually a result of somewhat messy calculations.

The BCs should for starters:

- be relaxed enough to allow the group action of global asymptotic symmetry transformations & finite mass excitations, e.g. multiple stars & black holes, because we want the model to be able to accommodate and describe these.
- be tight enough (i.e. fall-off fast enough for $r\to\infty$) for the Einstein-Hilbert action integral $S_{EH}[g]$ of the allowed metrics $g_{\mu\nu}$ to be well-defined with a finite value, possibly after renormalization.
- be consistent with the [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations).